# Maven Java EE configuration issue in Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) for JAX-RS 2.0

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I consistently see following error in 'Problems' view in my eclipse (version 4.4.2). Tried searching on google, but didn't find anything. Can someone help me understand and resolve this problem. I am able to build my codebase (spring based web application) fine, but would like to get to the root of this issue. Clicking on that issue's description takes me nowhere (i.e. doesn't open any file or settings). Here are the details:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.0 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.  experiment-poc      line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

**Description**: JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.0 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.

**Location**:    line 1

**Type**:        Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

Comment: What Maven dependencies are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this plugin in your pom.xml file

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
    <!-- i am using jdk 1.8-->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
```